# Blender stuck in Cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I am new to Blender. My model doesn't have subsurf modifier or any materials. In `Blender Render` my model renders properly, but in `Cycles Render` blender stuck. I have no idea why this is happening.

My model link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ucDpaQ2jrebaJRdSSQLY0wbUsF11_Yi9

[image: My Model]
[image: Blender Render Image]
[image: Cycles Stuck]

Comment: Add some pictures, don't frame a question that only gets answer to you, by adding only blend file!

Comment: @Yash.I thought blend file would be more helpful. Now images are added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I get from your file, cycles render, after a few seconds.

Maybe some driver/graphic card problem?

Hope it can help your troubleshooting.

[image]

Comment: I tried it. But still getting the same issue. Switched from Nvidia to intel.

Comment: as you mentioned it because of my Nvidia driver issue in Ubuntu.